# Volatility Modelling of Equity , error in code

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, finance, volatility

Dear StackExchange Community,

I am working on the codes by https://rpubs.com/rsayed/573439 to "measure the volatility spillovers and connectedness" using Diebold-Yilmaz Methodology (https://github.com/rhameysayed/Spillovers-and-Connectedness/blob/master/Connected__Spillover.Rmd).

## QUESTION

But I am facing a problem with the code when I use my dataset, it says I have incorrect number of dimensions (below) and I think I need to refine the code below based on the equations (1) and (2).

vol.fn <- function(history){asinh(sqrt(252*0.361*log(history[,3]/lag(history[,2]))^2))}

The author uses this code for data pulled from quantmod and also states that the above code follows these equations and I am completely lost as to how to fix it.

Equation1=
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:variance}
  \sigma^2_{it} = 0.361[ln(P^{max}_{i,t}) - ln(P^{min}_{i,t-1}))]^2 
\end{equation}

Equation2=
\begin{equation} 
  \sigma_{it} = sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{252*\sigma^2_{it}})
  \label{eq:stdev}
\end{equation}

I am completely confused on how to fix this problem and would really appreciate some insight, on whether its a problem with the code (refining the code based on the equation) or if its my dataset?

I included the dataset in the NOTE section (Note 1: Dataset) if anyone would find that helpful.
Would really appreciate it if someone in the community could help out with this problem or give some light on how to fix it Thank You Very Much!

**CODE**

```
df_my_data <- read.csv('C:/Users/s/Desktop/R/intro/data/data_stock_returns.csv')
str(df_my_data)

'data.frame':   5030 obs. of  74 variables:
 $ Index           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SXXP     : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ STJ   : num  0 -0.0248 0.0995 0.0611 -0.0456 ...
 $ ISP   : num  -0.021 -0.0021 -0.0212 0.023 -0.0173 ...

library(kableExtra)
vol.fn <- function(history){asinh(sqrt(252*0.361*log(history[,3]/lag(history[,2]))^2))}
vol1 <- lapply(df_my_data,vol.fn)
```

> Error in history[, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions
> Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)>

```
vol.data <- Reduce(merge.all,vol1)
vol.data <- na.omit(vol.data)
```

**NOTE 1:DATASET**

```
df_my_data<- structure(list(Date = c("4/1/2000","5/1/2000","6/1/2000","7/1/2000","10/1/2000","11/1/2000","12/1/2000",
"13/01/2000","14/01/2000","17/01/2000","18/01/2000","19/01/2000","20/01/2000",
"21/01/2000","24/01/2000","25/01/2000","26/01/2000","27/01/2000","28/01/2000","31/01/2000"), 
SXXP = c(0,0,0,0,0,-0.0014,-5.99E-06,0.0011,0.0051,0.00148,-0.0045,-0.0010,-0.00055,-0.00060,0.00108,
-0.0037,0.0024,0.0028,-0.0003,-0.0044),STJ = c(0,-0.024,0.09950.061052,-0.045,-0.0166,0.004,
-0.0505,0.0665,0.0083,-0.041,-0.0387,0.040,0,-0.004,-0.05183,-0.01366,
0.0623,-0.0326,-0.0494),ISP = c(-0.0209,-0.0020,-0.021220.0230,-0.0172,0.004,
-0.0076,-0.011,0.0143,-0.0327,-0.0173,-0.0299,0.0115,0.0345,
-0.0231,-0.0186,0.0244,-0.0354,-0.0174,-0.0225),
INGA = c(-0.0274,-0.00854, -0.00689,0.01961,0.00119,-0.01190,-0.03115,
-0.0108,0.02370,-0.00701,
-0.01059,0.00428,-0.0163,-0.00669,-0.03093,-0.00713,0.000566,0.0126,-0.00335,-0.0335)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

df_my_data

   Date         SXXP          STJ          ISP         INGA
1    4/1/2000  0.000000000  0.000000000 -0.020981703 -0.027431486
2    5/1/2000  0.000000000 -0.024830700 -0.002098372 -0.008543926
3    6/1/2000  0.000000000  0.099537037 -0.021224101 -0.006897636
4    7/1/2000  0.000000000  0.061052632  0.023030650  0.019615734
5   10/1/2000  0.000000000 -0.045634921 -0.017276138  0.001192973
6   11/1/2000 -0.001466894 -0.016632017  0.004786734 -0.011902231
7   12/1/2000 -0.000005990  0.004228330 -0.007684673 -0.031156279
8  13/01/2000  0.001141502 -0.050526316 -0.011744871 -0.010836622
9  14/01/2000  0.005177323  0.066518847  0.014313391  0.023706947
10 17/01/2000  0.001487096  0.008316008 -0.032755573 -0.007018666
11 18/01/2000 -0.004585252 -0.041237113 -0.017359781 -0.010597812
12 19/01/2000 -0.001014728 -0.038709677 -0.029994001  0.004283601
13 20/01/2000 -0.000557140  0.040268456  0.011564626 -0.016357380
14 21/01/2000 -0.000600562  0.000000000  0.034572354 -0.006690365
15 24/01/2000  0.001081653 -0.004301075 -0.023193973 -0.030932722
16 25/01/2000 -0.003745210 -0.051835853 -0.018663037 -0.007136289
17 26/01/2000  0.002465556 -0.013667426  0.024473692  0.000566533
18 27/01/2000  0.002832696  0.062355658 -0.035412342  0.012663463
19 28/01/2000 -0.000399600 -0.032608696 -0.017498440 -0.003359653
20 31/01/2000 -0.004428694 -0.049438202 -0.022540398 -0.033524404
```

Comment: Your function `vol.fn` appears to expect that you are passing an object of type `data.frame` as the `history` parameter, but when you do `lapply(df_my_data,vol.fn)` you are applying the `vol.fn` to the vectors representing the columns of `df_my_data`. You can do `lapply(df_my_data, print)` to confirm this fact.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you appear to be trying to accomplish above...

````r
df_my_data<- data.frame(Date = c('4/1/2000', '5/1/2000', '6/1/2000', '7/1/2000', '10/1/2000', 
                                 '11/1/2000', '12/1/2000', '13/01/2000', '14/01/2000', 
                                 '17/01/2000', '18/01/2000', '19/01/2000', '20/01/2000', 
                                 '21/01/2000', '24/01/2000', '25/01/2000', '26/01/2000', 
                                 '27/01/2000', '28/01/2000', '31/01/2000'), 
                        SXXP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0014, -5.99e-6, 0.0011, 0.0051, 0.00148, -0.0045, -0.0010, -0.00055, -0.00060, 0.00108, 
                                 -0.0037, 0.0024, 0.0028, -0.0003, -0.0044), 
                        STJ = c(0, -0.024, 0.0995, 0.061052, -0.045, -0.0166, 0.004, 
                                -0.0505, 0.0665, 0.0083, -0.041, -0.0387, 0.040, 0, -0.004, -0.05183, -0.01366, 
                                0.0623, -0.0326, -0.0494), 
                        ISP = c(-0.0209, -0.0020, -0.02122, 0.0230, -0.0172, 0.004, 
                                -0.0076, -0.011, 0.0143, -0.0327, -0.0173, -0.0299, 0.0115, 0.0345, 
                                -0.0231, -0.0186, 0.0244, -0.0354, -0.0174, -0.0225), 
                        INGA = c(-0.0274, -0.00854, -0.00689, 0.01961, 0.00119, -0.01190, -0.03115, 
                                 -0.0108, 0.02370, -0.00701, 
                                 -0.01059, 0.00428, -0.0163, -0.00669, -0.03093, -0.00713, 0.000566, 0.0126, -0.00335, -0.0335))

pairs <- colnames(df_my_data[ , -1 ]) |> combn(2)
vol.fn <- function(history, symbol1, symbol2){ asinh(sqrt(252 * 0.361 * log(history[, symbol1 ] / lag(history[, symbol2 ]))^2)) } 
vol.data <- apply(pairs, 2, function(x) vol.fn(history = df_my_data, symbol1 = x[ 1 ], symbol2 = x[ 2 ]))
colnames(vol.data) <- apply(pairs, 2, paste0, collapse = '/')
rownames(vol.data) <- df_my_data$Date

```
````